# Confusion on notation in documentation --python

Tags: python

The iter() method creates an object which can be iterated one element at a time.

These objects are useful when coupled with loops like for loop, while loop.

The syntax of iter() method is:

```
iter(object[, sentinel])
```

As an example using the sentinel bit of this code

```
with open('mydata.txt') as fp:
    for line in iter(fp.readline, ''):
        processLine(line)
```

and so the stop value is a blank line. But the , inside the [ ] array notation is confusion. Clearly the , comes between the object in the sentinel in my example and what would be more a complex example of code that would clarify this kind of use of a sentinel?

Comment: Read the `[]` as meaning that it is an optional parameter, not an array. So the `iter` takes either just an object, or an object followed by a comma and a sentinel.

Comment: [ ] in `iter(object[, sentinel])` is not array notation. It just says you may omit sentinel (plus the comma before it).